# Map of bus stops for Greyhound in Canada?

Tags: canada, greyhound, maps

In an upcoming trip I'm traveling from Montebello (a small town about an hour away from Montreal) to Montreal YUL airport.

The best transport I've been able to arrange so far is Greyhound into central Montreal, which although slow (taking well over two hours when a car would get there in an hour) is workable.

I would like to get off at the stop in Montreal closest to YUL, then take a taxi or Uber from there to YUL.  But what I'm having trouble figuring out is where any of the stops for Greyhound are - the website Greyhound.ca does not seem to have any maps that I can find.

On a sidenote Greyhound does have an option to go directly to YUL from Monelbello, but it involves a bus going to the same central Montreal location I'm looking at, then a very long time until a transfer bus which is too late for my flight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the station locator.  It appears that there is a stop at the airport itself:

https://www.greyhound.ca/en/locations/default.aspx#

Look for the station "Montreal Airport (pet)"

The only other station is in central Montreal.  If your connection to the airport is not in time for your flight, it appears you'll need to travel from the center to the airport by some other means.  Looking at this map, I do not see anything closer:

http://extranet.greyhound.com/Revsup/schedules/sa-50.pdf

According to Google maps, it's a little over 21 km by car, depending on the route, and bus 747 will get you there in 55 minutes.  You can get more detailed information at http://www.stm.info/en

Comment: Thanks, the station locator page was what I needed - although very annoying to use, when you find an individual station it does show you where a map with an exact location of the station.  The stop at the airport would be nice, but as I said sadly the transfer from the bus coming from Montebello is much too long for me to use that to reach the airport - it looks like getting off a stop or two earlier will be faster as it's closer to YUL.

Comment: One other thing of note - the station locator annoyingly only shows you maps for stations that sell tickets, intermediate stops like Cremazie or MTL Jean Talon come up in the station locator with just a short generic note , not even an address.

Answer (score 5):

I have been searching for this for a long time but never found any map (@phoog's diagram is the best I have ever seen, even though it does not show all the routes).

But bus transportation is quite sparse in Canada, there are few bus routes overall, and in particular rarely more than one bus route serving a town, so connections are often necessary. In your case, I know only a few routes, I don't think there is any other:

- Ottawa to Montreal through Montebello, serving all the small communities twice a day. It follows the Ottawa river on its north shore.
- Ottawa to Montreal "express", through Montreal airport. It follows the highway 40 on the south shore of the river.

On [a map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/45.5424/-74.0578), you can see Lachute in the northwest, served by the north shore branch, and the highway 40 on the south shore and Kirkland and Dorval (where the airport is) on the island. The routes do not intersect at all.

I let you search for the exact details (there is no link to schedule) if you want (as @phoog mentioned, the airport stop is called "Montreal Airport (pet), PQ" - there are other confusing entries).

A resource that I find a bit helpful is a map of [Quebec's bus routes](http://www.autobusmaheux.qc.ca/images/design/cartes/grandes/tous.png) by carrier to figure which one to take.

Comment: Thanks for the info, although the bus route map from your like appears not to include Montebello (which is more west and south than the map covers).  The station locator link from the other answer does include a map for each station you look for, so can get get an idea from there.

Comment: The map I linked is more for the rest of Quebec indeed but you can see the green line through Lachute which is your bus line. And yeah indeed the station locator might well be more useful.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I misunderstood.  Is there a map like that just within Montreal itself?

Answer (score 1):

The more rural bus routes in Quebec have been changing periodically in recent years, there is no up to date map and the maps that exist don't have a high level of detail.

If time is the primary concern, you're likely best getting off in [Laval Ouest West and finding a ride down](https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/Boulevard+Arthur-Sauv%C3%A9+%26+Boulevard+Sainte-Rose,+Laval,+QC/Montr%C3%A9al-Pierre+Elliott+Trudeau+International+Airport,+Montr%C3%A9al,+QC+H4S+2A5/@45.5191671,-73.8516018,12z/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x4cc9250ccdfc2c9b:0xd71be04ad37f3864!2m2!1d-73.8700305!2d45.5530632!1m5!1m1!1s0x4cc93d7753d8c92b:0x1e30a8791014678d!2m2!1d-73.7449195!2d45.4697382?hl=en) to the airport - that's the closest stop on the bus from Montebello to downtown Montreal.

Depending on the schedules, a slower alternative might be to take the bus the wrong way from Montebello to Ottawa and get on the direct Ottawa - Montreal Airport bus from there.